# How to keep a div constantly above a single point on the background?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which has a background of a map. The map is centred and has a background size of 'contain'. The page is responsive so when the window resizes, so does the map. I need to be able to have a div on top of a certain country on the map, and on resize of the background map, the div stays directly on top of it.

So far I have

```
<div id="map-holder">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The div with the class of placeholder is the div i wish to keep on top of a certain country. The div with map-holder for ID is the div with the map background. Content is just to keep it all in place.

CSS

```
    .content { 
    text-align: center;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;}

#map-holder {
    position: relative;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #F0F0F0;
    background-image: url(../images/image-mapster.min.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 30px;
}

.placeholder {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.placeholder img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.placeholder:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 45%;
    font-weight: bold;
    content: '+';
}
```

Comment: Sounds great! What's your question?

Comment: can you show us your code? what have you tried?

Comment: The question is how do I achieve this?

Comment: Are you open to Javascript solutions?  With 'contain' on the background div, I don't think you can do this in pure CSS - if you used 100% width and height instead, you could of course position the placeholder div with percentages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it's a little difficult, as I recall, when using background images.

Since the image is, technically speaking "content" you can use an inline image and suitable wrapping divs. The 'pins' can then be positioned using % based positioning values.

Here's a [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha) demo I made some time ago. This one has a tooltip too!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.map {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.map img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.box {
  width: 2%;
  height: 5%;
  background-image: url(http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/ncX/qyL/ncXqyLdcB.png);
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
}
#pin-1 {
  top: 25%;
  left: 38%;
}
.box:hover > .pin-text {
  display: block;
}
.pin-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25%;
  left: 110%;
  width: 300%;
  display: none;
}
.pin-text h3 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <img src="http://connect.homes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/200392710-0012.jpg" alt="" />
  <div id="pin-1" class="box">
    <div class="pin-text">
      <h3>My House</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although my solution is similar to yours, your placement seems to be pixel perfect, whereas my pinned element moves a bit depending on the screen width. Any insights?

Comment: To be honest, not really...I did this a long time ago so it's a little hazy. My structure is a little different of course and I threw in the universal reset too.

Comment: In your solution, you use a background image for the pin icon, that may lead to more accurate arithmetic by the CSS rendering engine.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I can think if actually putting an image over the map.

You can do this by having multiple CSS backgrounds. Just change your code for `#map-holder` to this:

```
#map-holder {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background: #F0F0F0;
    background-image: url(this_image_goes_on_top.png), url(your_map.jpg);
    background-size: contain, contain;
    background-position: center center, center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    padding: 30px; 
}
```

I made a little JSFiddle out of your code for demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/zamofL9g/1/

Comment: The only problem is I am actually going to be using multiple divs over multiple places, that are clickable and get populated by images selected from a lightbox after initially selecting the div. So I need it to be a div that goes over the map.